# Physiological ideal endurance event: short interval/short rest OR long interval/long rest

Tags: bicycling, endurance

**Simplified Version:**

For an endurance event that is 100% intervals, what is an ideal rest period to maximize things like lactate clearing, glycogen replenishing, etc?

**Details:**
There is a cycling endurance event called [Everesting](https://everesting.cc/) where you complete 8,848m of elevation gain in one ride. Recently the former racer Ronan McLaughlin set a mens world record completing it in [6:40](https://cyclingtips.com/2021/03/ronan-mc-laughlin-has-smashed-the-everesting-record-in-6-hours-40-minutes/) on a 810m (~5min/climb) segment of road where the [womens record-holder](https://blog.strava.com/everesting-world-record-20879/#:%7E:text=There%20was%20a%20Swiss%20rider,light%20attached%20to%20his%20helmet.) Emma Pooley chose a 6.8 km hill (~40min/climb).

From a physiology and metabolic perspective, which climb is better suited to the event and what would the "ideal climb" look like?

- 10x intervals of 40m ride, 10m rest
- 79x intervals of 5m ride, 45sm rest